# Which are  suitable local database (easy to handle with C++) for a small data set 

Tags: c++, database, oracle, api

The computer has already been installed ORACLE. But I didn't try ORACLE before, I just use sqlite...So, for now I want to create a database locally, and just insert one table. I want to use a test C++ program to read and write in this database. Is there something useful for using API about this? BTW, in the computer I saw SQL plus and SQL developer, but I didn't find the DBCA, which I know can be used to create table...help me, thanks a lot!!

BTW, my supervisor wants to me to test different kinds of database, which will be written in my report. So I want to test different kinds of databases, for the data is quite small, just 100 lines in a table is enough, but it will be applied in a big program, so I need to try different kinds of database locally, and not difficult for me to use C++ API...Because I just know little about database. I need some suggestions, thank a lot!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/nt.816/a99999/o4c00008.htm

Comment: You may have the Oracle *client* installed, but you would also need the Oracle *server* software.  Which I would not recommend -- it's really only intended to run on a server platform (gobs of memory, really fast disks, etc.)  If you absolutely have to have something local -- i.e. your DBA can't create you a sandbox on a development database server -- then I would recommend Oracle Express.

Comment: To clarify: SQLite is "bin-deployable" meaning all you need is the DLL and you're up and running.  Oracle, SQL Server and such are completely different animals.  There are separate pieces for the server (to host databases) and client (to access databases).

Comment: @David, your comment is an oversimplification. I run an 11g Standard Edition database on a Windows 7 box with a dual core CPU and 4GB of memory, standard issue SATA drives. While I wouldn't recommend this for a large mulituser environment, it's perfectly fine for what the OP seems to want.

Comment: How about MYSQL? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DCookie: please inform the OP about [how much would a Oracle server license cost](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/price-lists/index.html). I would definitely recommend MySQL for a local server. SQLite has a lot of limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I want to try MYSQL also, so I download one, and setup my database?

Comment: @m0skit0: Depending on the use (which, based on the post, might be academic/study use, with no intent on commercial follow-up), the license cost might not be an issue (i.e. freely downloadable, freely usable). But as said, this depends a lot on the intended use; commercial licenses for Oracle are expensive.

Comment: Still SQLite has some restrictions on [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) for example. I strongly suggest MySQL: it's open source, it's free, it setups very easily (on Linux at least), and runs on all major operating systems.

Comment: <devils-advocate> How about PostgreSQL? </devils-advocate>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend Oracle for handling small data sets, I do have a pointer to C++ API documentation.

http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=5&frame=

... and scroll to the bottom of the page for links to further information.

There's a choice of either using C++ with Oracle OCI API, or using C++ with Oracle Pro*C precompiler. The precompiler actually does produce code that uses the OCI API.

I have done some work with the Pro*C precompiler (using C as the implementation language, though, not C++), and it wasn't too bad. OCI tends to be quite low-level, but apparently writing direct OCI code has its uses, too.